# Differentiation of expression with 2 variables (quotient rule)

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

When I take the first partial derivative of this expression with respect to $x$, I get this (with help of the quotient rule):

The function is as follows: $$f(x,y)=\dfrac{x-y}{x+y}$$

1st partial derivative with respect to $x$: $$\dfrac{2y}{x^2+2xy+y^2}$$

Why can't I use the quotient rule again, if I want to find the 2nd partial derivative with respect to $x$? The solution told me I have to take $2y$ out of the expression and treat it as a constant and then solve for $1/(x^2+2xy+y^2)$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: " ... first partial derivative of this expression ... " --- What is the expression that you're taking a derivative of? So I imagine that you have a function $f$ that you need to find the derivative of, and you have written something about its derivative $f'$. But what is $f$ ?

Comment: The question is now updated.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$$
Then, if we derive w.r.t. x, we get
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{2y}{(x+y)^2}$$
I think both methods are equivalent:

- Quotient rule: knowing that the derivative of $2y$ w.r.t. $x$ is $0$
  $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)=\frac{\partial_{x}(2y)\cdot(x+y)^2-2y\cdot\partial_{x}((x+y)^2)}{(x+y)^4}=\frac{-2y\cdot 2(x+y)}{(x+y)^4}=\frac{-4y}{(x+y)^3}$$
  where $\partial_{x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$
- The method you book suggests: since $2y$ does not depend on $x$, we can take out of the derivative w.r.t. x
  $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=2y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}=2y\frac{-1\cdot2(x+y)}{(x+y)^4} = \frac{-4y}{(x+y)^3}$$

So you can go both ways, thank to the fact that $2y$ does not depend on $x$.

Comment: can you be more detailed regarding the quotient rule?

Comment: Hope that it is now clear.

Comment: @Economics_student: When you partially differentiate $f(x,y),$ w.r.t. $x$  for a moment pretend that all $y$ and its pure functions  are constants that do not survive partial differentiation. And functions mixed terms containing $y$ should treat $y$ it as a constant.

Comment: Thank you Davide, its now clear!